# Change background image but keep drawable to a view android xml

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable, android-bitmap, android-framelayout

I have a Framelayout which has some rounded corners through a drawable xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" >

    <!-- View background color -->
    <solid
            android:color="@color/colorPrimary" >
    </solid>

    <!-- The radius makes the corners rounded -->
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp" >
    </corners>
</shape>
```

Inside the FrameLayout i have 2 TextViews and an imageView which gets loaded with a bitmap programmatically. The problem is that i have tried everything to give the ImageView same rounded corners as the FrameLayout so i decided to replace the ImageView with another simple View (as FrameLayout or smth) and set the bitmap image as a background of the view. This didn't work either.

So is there any way in a view to set the drawable with the corners in the xml, and when later programmatically change the background with a bitmap to keep somehow the rounded corners with the new image loaded?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

**Step 1.** Go to `res/values` folder, create a xml file named `attrs.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="RoundedImageView">
        <attr name="topLeftCorner" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="topRightCorner" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="bottomRightCorner" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="bottomLeftCorner" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**Step 2.** Create a class that extends from AppCompatImageView, named `RoundedImageView`

```
public class RoundedImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

    private final Path path = new Path();
    private final float[] radii = new float[8];
    private final RectF rect = new RectF();

    public RoundedImageView(@NonNull Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RoundedImageView);
        try {
            int topLeftCorner = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_topLeftCorner, 0);
            int topRightCorner = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_topRightCorner, 0);
            int bottomRightCorner = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_bottomRightCorner, 0);
            int bottomLeftCorner = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_bottomLeftCorner, 0);
            radii[0] = topLeftCorner;
            radii[1] = topLeftCorner;
            radii[2] = topRightCorner;
            radii[3] = topRightCorner;
            radii[4] = bottomRightCorner;
            radii[5] = bottomRightCorner;
            radii[6] = bottomLeftCorner;
            radii[7] = bottomLeftCorner;
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        rect.left = 0;
        rect.top = 0;
        rect.right = getWidth();
        rect.bottom = getHeight();
        path.rewind();
        path.addRoundRect(rect, radii, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(path);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

**Step 3.** Use it from layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F00"
    android:gravity="center">

    <com.example.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android"
        app:bottomRightCorner="20dp"
        app:topLeftCorner="20dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Result**

[image]

**Benefit**

- You can set the corner radius for top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left.
- Work with Glide, Picasso library

**Limitations**

- The [ScaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType) is either [CENTER_CROP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType?authuser=1#CENTER_CROP) or [FIT_XY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType?authuser=1#FIT_XY)

Comment: Thats a very good solution. But is there a way to avoid Java and do this only with xml?? I mean...whatsapp and others do it by extending Imageview?

Comment: @james04 I don't think the standard android ImageView supports this feature, that why there are a lot of libraries in Github where developers must extend the ImageView to custom their look and behavior.

Comment: Can you please guide me to do the same in a VideoView? Thank you!!

Comment: @james04 In Stackoverflow, one question is specific to one problem so I think you can create a new question to ask about VideoView, because the answer might be different when you using VideoView. By the way, glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries to achieve it easily. But there is an other way to do. You can use your image within CardView. When you set cardCornerRadius feature the image corners which overlaying the cardview's corners will be rounded too.

Or try this

```
    ImageView yourImageView = findViewById(R.id.yourImageView);

    Bitmap bitmap =((BitmapDrawable) ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(R.drawable.anyPicture)).getBitmap();
    Bitmap roundedImageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas=new Canvas(roundedImageBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
    canvas.drawRoundRect((new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight())), 100, 100, paint); // You can adjust the roundness here

    yourimageView.setImageBitmap(roundedImageBitmap);
```

Comment: The problem is that i dont want evey corner to be round. Only top right and bottom left for example.!